# Unable to install Breeze in a new Laravel v10.x project because of a require conflict, how do I resolve this?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

```
williambrush@Williams-MacBook-Pro LandingPage2 % composer require laravel/breeze:1.9.2 --dev -W
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/breeze --with-all-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/breeze 1.9.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/breeze[v1.9.2].
    - laravel/breeze v1.9.2 requires illuminate/support ^8.42|^9.0 -> found illuminate/support[v8.42.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.16] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

I've been trying to figure this out but I'm at a total loss. I've scoured through SO for a while today but none of the solutions have helped out. I installed it by deleting the composer.lock and composer.json files but then nothing else works on the sytem. I'm developing on MacOS using Laravel HERD. I do have composer installed globally though.

Here are is my current .json file. breeze isn't listed cause of the issue. I looked through the .lock file and found there's ONE line for illuminate/filesystem and a ton of illuminate/support lines. Is filesystem needed? I heard support replaced it or that maybe that's what is conflicting? Not sure.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "framework"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: And what not clear in “ laravel/breeze v1.9.2 requires illuminate/support ^8.42|^9.0”? You install laravel 10, this version of breeze require 8 or 9.

Comment: mostly cause I'm new to programming in general and having ^8.x makes me think it means at LEAST v8 not specifically that version. it has v1.9.2 and ^8.42|^9.0 so I was confused with the formatting I guess between using v or ^ as version symbol. Good to know how it's used now though!

Answer (score -2):

Welp... seems a bit odd that it would be like this since I was following instructions from the docs, but this solved the issue:

`composer require laravel/breeze --dev -W`

That fully installed the package and added it to the composer.json file.

Laravel docs says to type this in `composer require laravel/breeze:1.9.2` but what gets installed from the line earlier is 1.26.3 which is kinda odd to me.

Comment: Where exactly does it say that? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze for the latest Laravel version has `composer require laravel/breeze --dev` - you most likely got the wrong version: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits